# didReceiveData Over write in subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, subclass

In the Xcode project, I have 2 classes say `ParentViewController` and another class `ChildViewController` which is the sub class of `ParentViewController`. In `ParentViewController` class we use `NSURLConnection`, `didReceiveData` and `connectionDidFinishLoading` to fetch some data from back end server. It works perfectly fine. Now in my `ChildViewController` I need to make connection and fetch data from backend as well. But if I add `didReceiveData` and `connectionDidFinishLoading` in `ChildViewController`, then the `didReceiveData` in `ParentViewController` seems doesn't work anymore. I am wondering why?

Also seems I have a lot of different requests send to backend, so my `didReceiveData` and `connectionDidFinishLoading` are overwhelminged with `(connect == someConnection)` statements. I am wondering any neat way to handle this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subclass will inherit the ParentViewController's connection delegate methods.  If you want the same behavior in the subclass, just don't implement the delegate methods there.

Another idea is to avoid the delegate methods altogether.  In iOS5, the NSURLConnection provides a better way to start a connection using a block for completion, so your code for each connection can be located in context, as follows:

```
NSURLRequest *requestA = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http..."]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestA queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // do what you need to do when requestA completes
}];

NSURLRequest *requestB = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http..."]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestA queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // do what you need to do when requestB completes
}];
```

I agree with the other answers that you might want to rethink the design if the app is doing a lot of remote requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to fetch data in a view controller, which is not where you should fetch data.

Move all your data fetching to the model objects. When the view controllers need something, they can request that the model load it. Then, even if the view controller goes offscreen, the model can still update correctly and let the view controllers know when it's done.

Typically you can have a single model object for each connection. For instance, if I were updating a person record from a server database, then the Person object would make a request for its own data. Then it's connectionDidFinishLoading would only have to deal with that one connection.

You still may want to put your connections though a central queue (`NSOperationQueue` for instance) so that you can avoid overwhelming your network connection with requests. But the delegate for each connection would be the relevant model object, not a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

network code in ObjectiveC can get overwhelming pretty fast. I recommend using a library to simplify the process. checkout https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking